# Why tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency() cannot increase without limitation?

Tags: c++, macos, parallel-processing, cpu, tbb

My MacOS system is 2 GHz 4 Intel Core i5, and when I set:

```
tbb::global_control gc(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 10);
```

I can only get 8 returned by `tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency()`.

When I increase `max_allowed_parallelism`, the max concurrency always returns 8 and cannot increase.

How is `max_concurrency()` controlled inside tbb ?

Comment: To increase or decrease `max_concurrency()`, one shall create `tbb::task_area` object and execute some functor or lambda: `tbb::task_arena( 10 ).execute( [&] { std::cout << tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency(); } );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `max_allowed_parallelism` allows you to *limit* the max number of worker threads.
- `max_concurrency()` returns the concurrency level of the `task_arena` currently used by the calling thread. If the thread has not yet initialized the task scheduler, **returns the concurrency level determined automatically for the hardware configuration**.

This indicates that your current hardware supports having 8 *active*/*running* threads at any point in time and there's little point in creating more worker threads than what is supported by hardware. I suggest leaving `max_allowed_parallelism` at its default value and you'll get the most out of your hardware.

Example - When I run this program on a computer that I *know* has 12 hyperthreaded cores (meaning, it can run 2 hardware threads per core), the output will be 24. If I run it on another computer with 6 HT cores, it'll output 12.

```cpp
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace oneapi;

int main() {
    std::cout << tbb::this_task_arena::max_concurrency() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That partially solves my question. So may I ask how `max_concurrency()` is determined by tbb?
For example, when I use 2 GHz 4 Intel Core i5, the max_concurrency() returns 8. However, when I use "FROM debian:bullseye-slim as builder" and set the machine core equaling 4, the max_concurrency() returns 4. Both of the them have 4 cores.

Comment: @PeijiaYu You're welcome! I looked at a table over intel's Core i5 CPUs and it seems most of those have 4 hyperthreaded cores, so `max_concurrency()` returning 8 seems very reasonable. I don't know what "FROM debian:bullseye-slim as builder" means unfortunately.

Comment: @PeijiaYu If that "FROM debian:bullseye-slim as builder" line is from a docker installation, then try to avoid setting a specific limit: _"By default, containers have no specific CPU limits and can use as much CPU as the host machine has available"_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. "FROM debian:bullseye-slim as builder" uses Debian GNU/Linux operating system in docker, which is built on the Debian 11 "Bullseye" release. This is my docker resources allocation: 4 CPUs, 2GB swap, 10GB memory, and 96GB Virtual disk limit. 
However, I get max_concurrency = 8 for my MacOS system. And I get max_concurrency = 4 for GNU/Linux operating system in docker. Both of them have 4 cores.
I am wondering how the max_concurrency is determined.

Comment: @PeijiaYu `max_concurrency` is determined like I said in the answer. You can however put further limitations on the maximum concurrancy by specifying a limit in docker. I suggest that you don't.

Comment: I fully understand now. Thanks a lot! So the `max_concurrency()` is determined by the number of cores multiplied by the hardware threads for each core?

Comment: @PeijiaYu In a machine with an architecture where that forumla makes sense, yes, exactly. You can have multiple CPUs too (so the total number of cores could be X times the number of cores in one CPU) and distribute the threading in different ways but, yes.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what is the major difference between `tbb::global_control gc(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 10);` and `tbb::task_arena( 10 ).execute( ... )`? They are two independent values, but which one shall be preferred in what situation? Is it right that the number of worker threads participating in e.g. `tbb::parallel_for` is the minimum of `max_allowed_parallelism` and `max_concurrency`?

Comment: @Fedor I should have linked to the documentation I found when I wrote the answer, but I found [this](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Migration_Guide/Task_Scheduler_Init.html) now which seems to explain the different options pretty well.